# How to solve Runtime Error in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am following a course on PluralSight on C# Fundamentals all is going well until I try to debug the application inside visual studio or even run without debug I get the exception below. Even with simple Hello World I get this exception also. So far I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio the problem occurs again, also to mention I create the folder structure through the terminal I am not sure this is relevant but better to mention it.

I am using Visual Studio Version Version 16.4.2.

The runtime error:

> An handled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot fund the file specified.

The code:

```cs
using System;

namespace Gradebook
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string args[])
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {args[0]}!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Please do not post pictures of code but rather the code portion that produces the error as text, as described in FAQ on [mcve]. 2) What version of Visual Studio are you trying this on? 3) What .Net Framework version?

Comment: 1)Visual Studio Version Version 16.4.2
2).Net Framework version 3.1.0

Comment: OK, so you are using VS 2019 but only framework 3.1? is there a specific reason for going so low? Try again using Framework 4.5 or higher.

Comment: I have no reason i am new to c# in general started today when i installed Visual Studio it installed everything together.

Comment: Then go into your project's properties, application tab, switch target framework to 4.5, retry. Also: you are using a console application with parameters. To test its output properly, you need to call your .exe from a command line with parameters, e.g. "myApp.exe Filip".

Comment: When i test it from command prompt its working fine, when i try to debug from Visual Studio i get this error, also i am having .netFrameWork version 4.8 sorry my mistake

Comment: Well, test in higher Framework. You should then get an IndexOutOfRange exception instead, since args[] is then null.

Comment: When i got Target Framework it says 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as answer so I can add screenshots.

Increase Framework Version to 4.5. To do so, you need to enter project properties. You get there by e.g. right clicking your Project => Properties or by double clicking "Properties" in your solution explorer:

[image: Project Properties]

The Application tab should be the first tab. There you find a dropdown with which you can specify your Target Framework version:

[image: Application tab]

While you are in your project's properties, you might as well provide default command line arguments to prevent said "IndexOutOfRange" error in debug:

[image: Command line arguments]

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else has this issue, I am also going through the same course. The issue is that when you create the file through the command line, you don't have a solution file created. So then, I thought maybe I could select "Open a local folder" in the visual studio menu, navigate to Program.cs and execute it from there. If you try to do that, you will get this error

Instead, you need to click "Open a project or solution". Notice that it lets you open a project file in addition to the solution. So even though you don't have a solution (.sln) file, you can click on the .csproj file. Then after doing so, you will be able to directly run the code in visual studio. Also, it will automatically create a solution file.

Comment: Thanks your solution worked. But how do we edit the launch.json (present in .vscode folder) file as shown in the C# course to debug command line argument?